# Dictionary contains list, but I get 'IndexError: list index out of range' when I try to target it

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of dictionaries of the form:

```
[{"Title": ["Harry Potter"], "Author": ["J.K.Rowling"]}, 
 {"Title": ["Lord of the Rings"], "Author": ["J.R.R. Tolkien"]}]
```

I'm trying to write it to a csv file using the following code:

```
for dic in lis:
    title = dict["Title"][0]
    author = dict["Author"][0]

    csvWriter.writerow([title, author])
```

But I'm getting an IndexError that says my list index is out of range.  But if I remove the [0] from the end of my dict["Title"]...then it places a list into my csv file.

Even more confusing, if I try to encode the item:

```
dict["Author"].encode('utf-8')
```

It says something like, "list object doesn't have method, decode()"

It's definitely a list...so why am I getting this error?

I'm using python 2.7

EDIT:

So this example was a simplified version of what I'm actually dealing with.  I've scraped a website using scrapy and have been returned a json file.  The json file, when decoded, is a list containing dictionaries which contain more lists.

items.json:

```
[{"Title": ["Harry Potter"], "Author": ["J.K.Rowling"]}, 
 {"Title": ["Lord of the Rings"], "Author": ["J.R.R. Tolkien"]}]
```

My code:

```
import json
import csv


with open('items.json', 'r') as f:
    op = f.read()
    json = json.loads(op)


with open("data.csv", "wb") as f:
    csvWriter = csv.writer(f)
    csvWriter.writerow(['title', 'author'])

    for dic in json:
        title = dic['Title'][0]
        author = dic['Author'][0]

        csvWriter.writerow([title, author])
```

When I run this code, I get the IndexError

Comment: Please provide [MCVE] - something that's copy-pasteable to interpreter and exposes your issue.

Comment: Your csvWriter.writerow method is obviously expecting a list of lists, because everything before that runs without an error. You could have just looked at them in the debugger to know they were exactly as you expected, up until that point.

Comment: Also try not to use class names as variable names.

Comment: You are reusing the builtin `dict` and `list` names and masking them. This can have really weired side effects.

Comment: Just to clear something up, my actual variable names are not List and Dict.  I just used that for clarity.  I've edited the original post so as to avoid further confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Argument to cscWriter.writerow should be a list of lists.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html
If you want to encode, use:
    dict["Author"][0].encode('utf-8')

Comment: I've tried this, it gives me an IndexError that says list index is out of range

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue.

Buried within my json file were empty lists.  I didn't see them at first, but my program found them.  This issue is solved